# QuickSort in descending order is not working properly on duplicate entries

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I am facing some problem with the recursive quick sort algorithm. The elements are not sorted in the correct order. The input data are Strings with duplicate entries as well. I am using an integer to differentiate between ascending order( 1 ) and descending order ( -1) sort. The pivot is the mid element. Whenever the duplicate entries are compared( compareTo(String s) will return 0),  i compare the current indices and return a negative number if the index of the string being compared is more than the index of the other.I am not sure as to what exactly is going wrong.
Below is the code

```
// Quick sort Algorithm
public void sort(int left, int right)
{
    int  i = left, j = right;
    String mid;

    mid = (String)vect.elementAt((left + right)/2);

    while (i <= j)
    {
        // Compare the elements to the left
        while ((i < right) && 
                (compare((String)vect.elementAt(i), mid) < 0))
            i++;
        // Compare the elements to the right
        while ((j > left) && (compare((String)vect.elementAt(j), mid) > 0))
            j--;

        if (i <= j)
        {
            if(i!=j)
                swap(i, j);

            i++;
            j--;

        }
    }
    // Recursively call the sort method until indices cross.
    if(left < j)
        sort(left, j);
    if(i < right)
        sort(i, right);
}

/*
 * Compare method to compare the elements.
 * type = 1, for ascending sort
 * type = -1, for descending sort
 */
public int compare(String firstObj, String secondObj)
{
    int resCompare = firstObj.compareTo(secondObj)*type;
    if(resCompare == 0)
    {
        int index_firstObj = vect.indexOf(firstObj);
        int index_secObj = vect.indexOf(secondObj);
        if(index_firstObj < index_secObj)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
    return resCompare;
}
// Swap the elements at i and j.
public void swap(int i, int j)
{
    String tmp1 = (String)vect.elementAt(i);
    String tmp2 = (String)vect.elementAt(j);

    vect.setElementAt(tmp1, j);
            vect.setElementAt(tmp2, i);

}
```

Example : 
input = {"AA","BB","zz","cc","aa","AA","PP","hh" };
Ascending sort
output = {"AA","AA","BB","PP","aa","cc","hh","zz"};
Descending sort
output = {"zz","hh","cc","BB","aa","PP","AA","AA"};

The problem in the algorithm may not work for ascending order sort as well on some other input data. So any help in finding the glitch in the code/logic will be really helpful.Thanks in advance.

Solved:
There is no need to find index_firstObj and index_SecondObj. Just don't do anything if the resCompare is zero.
    public int compare(String firstObj, String secondObj)
    {
        int resCompare = firstObj.compareTo(secondObj)*type;
            return resCompare;
    }

Comment: while the ﬁrst binary search was published in 1946, the ﬁrst published
binary search without bugs did not appear until 1962.
—Jon Bentley, Programming Pearls (1st edition), pp.35–36 -- no one gets these things right at the first attempt.

Comment: Does it work if you change the line `int index_secObj = vect.indexOf(secondObj);` to `int index_secObj = vect.  lastIndexOf(secondObj);` in method `compare`?

Comment: No.. It didn't work. When i debug, the lastIndexOf(secondObj) is always the same as the indexOf(secondObj).

Answer (score 0):

What if i or j become the mid? and the other one is yet not the mid? doesnt that arise problems also? You might need to check if one of them becomes the mid.